# Cant build my Xamarin.Forms project after recent updates

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im getting this error. And dont have a clue of what to do...
Thanks.

**Full error**

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA0000: Unhandled exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/Users/eduardoneto/PROJETOS/myapp/myapp.Droid/obj/Debug/lp/78/jl/res/**/*.png".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0015e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:223 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:106 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions)
  at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile (System.String sourceFullPath, System.String destFullPath, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystem.Unix.cs:54 
  at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x00056] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:74 
  at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:56 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfChanged (System.String source, System.String destination) [0x00033] in <e29c048b3b5443a3a8a19c4ed24d3a3a>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.CopyIfChanged (System.String source, System.String destination) [0x00000] in <e29c048b3b5443a3a8a19c4ed24d3a3a>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.Crunch.DoExecute (System.Linq.IGrouping`2[TKey,TElement] imageGroup) [0x00095] in <e29c048b3b5443a3a8a19c4ed24d3a3a>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AsyncTaskExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass0_1`1[TSource].<WhenAll>b__0 () [0x00000] in <e29c048b3b5443a3a8a19c4ed24d3a3a>:0  (XA0000) (myapp.Droid)

**VS version**

=== Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac ===

Version 8.5 (build 3183)
Installation UUID: cae51bb2-5449-434c-a2e8-1562ce0250f5
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Xamarin.Mac 6.14.1.39 (d16-5 / 30e8706b4)

    Package version: 608000123

=== Mono Framework MDK ===

Runtime:
    Mono 6.8.0.123 (2019-10/1d0d939dc30) (64-bit)
    Package version: 608000123

=== Roslyn (Language Service) ===

3.5.0-beta4-20125-04+1baa0b3063238ed752ad1f0368b1df6b6901373e

=== NuGet ===

Version: 5.4.0.6315

=== .NET Core SDK ===

SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.200/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    3.1.200
    3.1.102
    3.1.101
    3.1.100
    3.0.101
    3.0.100
    2.1.701
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.8.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks

=== .NET Core Runtime ===

Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    3.1.2
    3.1.1
    3.1.0
    3.0.1
    3.0.0
    2.1.16
    2.1.15
    2.1.14
    2.1.13
    2.1.12

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.6.12.26
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Updater ===

Version: 11

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 11.3.1 (15715)
Build 11E146

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 6.14.1.39 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 30e8706b4
Branch: d16-5
Build date: 2020-02-20 16:41:47-0500

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 10.2.0.100 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d16-5/988c811
Android SDK: /Users/eduardoneto/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        7.1 (API level 25)
        8.0 (API level 26)
        8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 29.0.6
SDK Build Tools Version: 29.0.2

Build Information: 
Mono: c0c5c78
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-5@fc18c54
ProGuard: xamarin/proguard/master@905836d
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.28.0@46204c4
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-5@9f4ed4b

=== Microsoft Mobile OpenJDK ===

Java SDK: /Users/eduardoneto/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25
1.8.0-25
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Android SDK Manager ===

Version: 16.5.0.39
Hash: 6fb4c79
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-5
Build date: 2020-02-20 23:25:56 UTC

=== Android Device Manager ===

Version: 16.5.0.71
Hash: 49194e8
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-5
Build date: 2020-02-20 23:26:18 UTC

=== Xamarin Designer ===

Version: 16.5.0.471
Hash: 35aa4889d
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-5
Build date: 2020-02-25 00:52:08 UTC

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 13.14.1.39 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 30e8706b4
Branch: d16-5
Build date: 2020-02-20 16:41:48-0500

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.4.3
Hash: db27525
Branch: 1.4-release
Build date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 21:20:18 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 805003183
Git revision: 60e06e010baa677204535600661dda3fb4677c2f
Build date: 2020-03-20 06:18:03-04
Build branch: release-8.5
Xamarin extensions: 60e06e010baa677204535600661dda3fb4677c2f

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.15.3
Darwin 19.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.3.0
    Thu Jan  9 20:58:23 PST 2020
    root:xnu-6153.81.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Do you have any images in Android resources folder with space or special characters in name? and looks like android project is set to use Nougat which doesnt seem to have been installed on your machine

Comment: delete obj/bin folder of your app and build the app again.

Comment: Which line of the code thrown the error? Could you provide more details?

Comment: Prteek no i didn't had any images in this conditions. magicandre1981 i alredy tried this, thanks. Hey wendy zang - MSFT, there's no line, the error was on compile time. Thanks guys. I found a solution for the problem. It seems that was related of my xamarin.android version. In the new version i had to enable =><AndroidUseAapt2>true</AndroidUseAapt2>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution that i found:

**On AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
<AndroidUseAapt2>true</AndroidUseAapt2>
```

**Android build Config**

[image: Android build Config]

Comment: @Eduardo C. Neto In my VS 2019 for MAC, this value is true. still I am getting error. `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk'.` I am not able to run any android project.

Comment: I have the same problem